# Debug resourses error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error that 'R' is not resolved `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

Comment: what is your build tool version.. check in build.gradle

Comment: try clean project from build-> clean and rebuild your project.